# VBA Auto Update Image Dimensions in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Edit: 17-07-2018 found a solution to retrieve image dimensions in Excel.

I've created a code to retrieve image files in Excel and it's working fine, but once I resize the image it doesn't automatically update its value I need to shift between images before and then go back to the resized imaged to get the value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim mypic As Picture

   If Target.Address = "$A$4" Then
        Me.Pictures.Visible = False
        With Range("e2")
            For Each mypic In Me.Pictures
                If mypic.Name = .Text Then
                    mypic.Visible = True
                    mypic.Top = .Top
                    mypic.Left = .Left
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next mypic
        End With

        With ActiveSheet
            s = Round(.Shapes(.Range("e2").Value).Height / 72 * 2.54, 2) & "cm"
            y = Round(.Shapes(.Range("e2").Value).Width / 72 * 2.54, 2) & "cm"


        MsgBox "Picture dimensions are " & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Height: " & s & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Width: " & y

            .Range("Q5") = s
            .Range("Q6") = y

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The code as above is there a way to automatically update the values without closing the Excel file or shifting between images.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is the cm measured on a 50in 4K or an iPhone4?

Comment: no cm as Centimeter to be viewed on a PC normal screen. Does that matter?

Comment: OK, I'll bite. What exactly are the physical dimensions of a 'normal' screen and what resolution is the display set at?

Comment: David, my point is that a cm measurement is completely relative to the equipment and display settings. Open an image on your 'normal' PC and resize it to what you want. Now go into the display settings and change the screen resolution. Then plug in another monitor, bigger or smaller or even the same size from a different manufacturer. Finally, (if you have access to one) output the display to a projector or high-def TV.

Comment: You should quickly realize the the term cm is completely subjective without a display standard. If you are gauging the cm on a display standard, you're really just counting pixels which is what non-vector image sizes are really counted in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification I didn't know such thing before about image sizes being different according to monitors. What you advice me to o at that case, I'm asking to get the size px or whatever which is static on all screens

Comment: Yes, and consider a design target. I avoid graphic design due to that side of my brain not working but I have repaired msoffice word documents that people loaded multiple 20Mb high-rex photos from a modern digital camera. You don't need a 20Mb .jpg to put a 2"x3" image on an A4 piece of paper.

Comment: Thanks ... do you have a code example to share please

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As I mentioned, I really don't do graphic design and if I play with images, it's in C, not VBA. My comments have just been to give you the benefit of my past experience.